# How can I backup my computer hard drive?

Tags: backup

I am using Lubuntu 14.04. It is the only OS on the computer. Is there any software I can use to backup to a cd or dvd?

Comment: Do you want to backup your whole HDD to DVD drive? You'll need external hard drive disk or at least big pendrive when you want to backup only part of your data.

Comment: I want to backup whole hard drive. Also, do you think it would it be fruitful for me to upgrade to 14.10? any advantage? with this 14.04 am having some difficulties.

Comment: To backup your hard drive You can use `dd` command. Do you know how your drive is called, or not? (eg.`/dev/sda`) Also, I'm using 14.04, at least it's stable and everything works for me.

Comment: I entered dd and nothing happened. then /dev/sda-->  bash: permission denied. I guess the drive is c://

Comment: I am downloading lubuntu 14.10-desktop-i386.iso file. maybe it will work better, I don't know.

Comment: seems it downloaded ok. in tmp folder. could you tell me how to install it from there please? I tried disk image writer and mounter. nothing happened.

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding we had a night here. In linux drives are not called like C: it's more like `/dev/sda`.. You can find out drive names by `sudo fdisk -l`. We ude `dd` like this: `dd --if=/dev/sda --of=backup.img` where input file (if) is your drive name and output file (of) is you bacup file. To use that properly you have to be in your external drive location by terminal. Also, if you get permission errors use `sudo` before your command.

Comment: You don't need to install anything.  Everything should work fine. If you still don't know drive name please post `sudo fdisk -l` output by editing your post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: Additionally for a [backup strategy look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Comment: nothing seems to be working except I can get online ok. terminal doesn't open anything. backup to dvd doesn't work. maybe I need a course in how to use everything. where could I get one?  suggestions?

Comment: nothing but problems since I began with linux mint and now lubuntu. (lost sheep) I've tried everything everyone has suggested.

Comment: well, i just downloaded duplicity-0.6.25.tar.gz backup file and Run says 'no such file'. but it's in tmp folder.

Comment: I wonder what app or file i could use to check all HardDrive files?

Comment: I don't even know if 14.10 installed. is there a study course I can buy?

Answer (score 0):

Roland,

You can mix applications from different Ubuntu flavors, and even have 2 or more interfaces side by side.
http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

```
sudo apt-cache search burning | grep -i cd/dvd
# It will give you some options
# brasero - CD/DVD burning application for GNOME
sudo apt-get install brasero
```

My favorite is Brasero, it is straightforward and a rock solid software.